# Adding panel to container with Java's swing

Tags: java, swing

I have made two panels and then added in third panel. How can I add a panel to show up on screen?

Here is my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LibraryFront {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
    JPanel cards;
    final String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
    final String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

    // Create the panel that contains the "cards".
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
    cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);

    Container c = getContentPane(); //this gives error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
 *I noticed now that you took the code snippet (part) from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html and placed it directly into your main method. That code is just part of the full program implementation at [CardLayoutDemo.java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java). You need to take a look at that code.*

There are a lot of little errors with your code. Here is a working implementation

```
//it is good practice to only import the packages you need
//so that you know exactly what you are dealing with
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LibraryFront {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //f1 is the JFrame
        //f1.getContentPane() would return the Container
        //but you do not actually need to add directly to it
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        JPanel cards;
        final String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
        final String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";

        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

        // Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
        cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);

        //adjust background colors just so you can see what is happening
        cards.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        card1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        card2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        //set the layout to BorderLayout
        // add the cards JPanel to the center
        f1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f1.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f1.setSize(400, 300);
        f1.setTitle("Test Frame");
        f1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LibraryFront is not the container. `JFrame` f1 is, `f1.getContentPane()` should work and you also need to add panels to JFrame and set it to visible if not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Container c = f1.getContentPane();
```

Call the method on the `JFrame`, not on your own `LibraryFront` class.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you an error because your class `LibraryFront` does not contain a `getContentPane()` method.  Instead call that method on the frame.

Do something like:

```
f1.getContentPane().add(cards);
```

Comment: thanks it worked but even if use f1.add(cards) , it also worked. then why i need getcontentpane()  . also my only first card1 is visible , how can i toggle the other card2 to become visible on start of app

Comment: You have to tell the layout to show the other card.  Take a look at the tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: He did look there - in fact the code in the question is directly from the page - he did not however look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java